# Can "would" be used in affirmative for being less direct?

Tags: will-would

Can "would" be used in affirmative form for being less direct?

Situation:
I have got a request from a business counterparty.  After we agreed on the way of taking it forward, I need to pass to my peer to follow it thro.  So, I need to write to inform them and copying my peer.

Says Peter is my peer that will follow it.

Can I say

> Peter would follow it through.

I'm trying to say "Peter will follow it through" in a less direct way.  I would like to make it less direct because Peter is in the email loop.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use *would* in this way.  In this context *would* is interpreted as a conditional, and the reader will expect a reason why Peter *can't* do it.

> Peter **would** follow up on the email -- but he's out of town at the moment.

I understand that *will* sounds like you're giving Peter a command.  One alternative is to instead use *can*, or *could*, or *is able to*, along with a question directed at Peter himself.

> Peter **can** follow up on this, since it's urgent.  Peter, what's your availability?

Adding *I think* also helps make it much less direct.

> **I think** Peter could follow up on this by end-of-day tomorrow.  Peter, is that doable?

*Should* is also good, to imply some degree of expectation.  Again you can mitigate this with some variation on *I think*:

> **I believe** Peter **should** have some time to work on this issue.  Peter, are you booked or do you have some free bandwidth?

There are, of course, many more ways to express this, including all kinds of modern workplace idioms and buzzwords.